# Как сохранить порядок в Paralells.For

Tags: c#

Есть 100 урл. Хочу к ним сделать гет-запрос.

```
Parallel.For(0, urls.Count(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100}, (i) =>
{
    var html = new WebClient().Get(urls[i]);
    lst.Add(html);
});
```

Как сохранить порядок в lst? Чтобы он совпадал с порядком в urls

Comment: Используйте как-то параметр `i`. Например `lst[i] = html`, если lst — это массив

Comment: Либо используйте PLINQ вместо Parallel, там есть метод `AsOrdered`

Comment: Мне кажется, что требование порядка в параллельных запросах убивает саму идею о паралельности, не?

Comment: Ну и да, `lst` должен быть потокобезопасен, иначе он может сломаться

Comment: Вот-вот, мне нужна потокобезопасность)

Comment: @АндрейNOP в идеале создать какой нить Class и его потокобезопасным сделать

Comment: `...AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(...).Select(...do something...).AsOrdered().ToList()`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это куда

Comment: Что куда? Это решение вашей задачи с PLINQ

Comment: @AK, не совсем, требуется не упорядочивание выполнения запросов, а упорядочивание возврата результата. Я не смотрел как внутри PLINQ сделан, но мы можем просто ждать пока выполнится i-ая операция, потом вернуть ее результат и ждать уже (i+1)-ю и т.д., если какая-то уже выполнена, то ее результат просто возвращается без ожидания

Comment: Можно вообще что-то типа такого написать, если хочется самостоятельно прочувствовать: `for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) tasks[i] = Task.Run(...); for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) lst[i] = await task[i];` здесь запись в коллекцию будет выполняться в одном потоке, потокобезопасность для нее не нужна. Но да, реализовать DegreeOfParallelism вручную будет уже сложнее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114004/discussion-between-radzhab-and--nop).

Comment: `WebClient` устарел, используйте `HttpClient` вместо него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для начала ответьте себе на вопрос что ВЫ хотите получить:

- порядок в самих запросах, либо
- порядок в ответах.

в первом случае не нужно использовать идею параллельности.
во втором всего лишь отсортировать результат, или использовать словарь.